# Show and Hide elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm currently working on this:

```
<div id='container'>

<div id="box1">
<h1>Share it!</h1>
</div>    

<div class="box" style="visibility: hidden">
<a href="#" class="bt btleft">Facebook Button here</a>
<a href="#" class="bt btright">Twitter Button here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

```
$("#container").hover(function () {
   $("#container div").css("visibility","visible");
},
function () {
   $("#container div").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9USt/3/

What I want to achieve is something like the website [Mashable](http://mashable.com)

What i want to achieve is when I hover on the word "share It!", it will auto hide and show the links (on the same exact location). I've been stuck here for a while, can someone help?

Comment: you need to hide box1 upon hover and show upon hover out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little bit of changes in your HTML, this is something you might find useful. Simply use the [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) functionality of jQuery to toggle the states.

**HTML**

```
<div class="social">
     <h1>Share this</h1>

    <div class="networks">
        <p>Twitter</p>
        <p>Facebook</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.networks {
    display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".social").hover(function() {
    $("h1", this).hide();
    $(".networks", this).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(".networks", this).hide();
    $("h1", this).fadeIn();
});
```

The `fadeIn()` is just added for a nice fading effect, you can also use `.show()` there.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppksR/).

Comment: wow! this is the exact same thing! thanks @MarcoK. thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the html function which load dynamically content in a parent. 
Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/slown1/TqGFQ/

Here is the solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='container' style="border:1px solid red;">
    <h1>Share it!</h1>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#container").hover(function () {
    $("#container").html("<a href='#' "+
     "class='bt btleft'>"+"Facebook Button here</a><a href='#'" +
     "class='bt btright'>Twitter Button here</a>'");
    },
      function () {
          $("#container").html("<h1>Share it!</h1>");
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to hide box1 upon hover and show upon hover out

```
 $("#container").hover(function () {
        $('#box1').hide();
        $('.box').show();     
   },
  function () {
       $('.box').hide();     
       $('#box1').show();
   });
```

and your html

```
<div id="box1">
<h1>Share it!</h1>
</div>    

<div class="box" style="display:none">
<a href="#" class="bt btleft">Facebook Button here</a>
<a href="#" class="bt btright">Twitter Button here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: hi manish, thank you for your input. unfortunately, if i remove my cursor. the "share it" text is missing. it should revert back to it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? I think its simple and works for you

http://jsfiddle.net/mztcn/

```
$("#container").hover(function () {
    $(".box").css("visibility", "visible");
}, function () {
    $(".box").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```